# How can a SWF inject content into a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, security

By embedding the follow SWF code, when ran in an individual page a new tab comes up with the desired URL and an ad bar over the top. There is no user interaction required.

```
<embed width="1" height="1" align="middle"
       pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain"
       name="blog" bgcolor="000000" wmode="transparent" quality="high"
       src="http://i1177.photobucket.com/albums/x348/hosting504/red.swf" 
       flashvars="web=www.agitehabbero.com/index.php&creador=supercito">
```

If the code is embedded into a frame, then no new tabs are created, and rather the frame is modified to add the html page.

**Edit: There is NO JAVASCRIPT on the page.**

How can a SWF file do this? (Inject content into an webpage)?

Comment: I tried embedding the code into an iframe and a regular frame, but both cases the code opened (or tried to open) a new window/tab instead of modifying the frame. Are you sure it modified the frame itself?

Comment: I'd better get that bounty :)

Comment: Your question is misleading, and you accepted an answer which dissasembles for the worst solution possible, found in that red.swf file.

Comment: Tiberiu: The accepted solution does not require 'AllowScriptAccess' to be set to always. Yours does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This ActionScript3.0 code will inject an anonymous function, then execute it while passing the single param "hello":
`ExternalInterface.call("function(msg){ alert(msg); }", "hello");` (this gets executed like this Javascript code: `function(msg){ alert(msg); }("hello");`).

Since you can inject code, you can write the code to manipulate the document (add elements, modify styles, change element values, etc.). For example this AS3 code: `ExternalInterface.call("function(){ document.write(\"Hello, world!\"); }");` will display "Hello, world!" on the HTML page.

Also, from the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html):

- In the object tag for the SWF file in the containing HTML page, set the following parameter:
  `<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />`
- In the SWF file, add the following ActionScript:
  `flash.system.Security.allowDomain(sourceDomain)`

I tested all of the above, and it works just fine on my browsers: Google Chrome 19, Internet Explorer 8, Firefox 12.

As you requested, no javascript on the document side :)

Comment: This is scary, I really need to get adblock installed.

Comment: @o.v. Don't worry, add hosting providers embed swf content with allowScriptAccess=never (including Google Ads).

Comment: @o.v. Don't think this is just flash. When you install ANY plugin, you give it the same privileges as you give to your browser. Plugins are NOT sandboxed by the browser and they can do almost anything they want to your system.

Comment: @MrMalayev Plugins and Flash running on a internet page are sandboxed, they cannot touch the system. Additionally, Flash can be sandboxed to not touch the page on which it is embedded.

Comment: Nope, you are wrong. Plugins are not sandboxed and they have the same privileges as the browser to be able to do anything to the system. I think what you mean are extensions.

Comment: I think you mean Internet Explorer and Firefox. You are right, they can do anything. However Flash itself is not the problem here, but a swf running inside Flash.

Answer (score 3):

There is a class in AS called [`ExternalInterface`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html). It helps flash communicate with JS (call a js function or JS call a flash function). Then throw DOM the can add content into a page. It could be this.

Comment: I thought it was this, however there is no other Javascript in the page. It's just the SWF.

Comment: It doesn't matter what Javascript exists on the page; `ExternalInterface` calls the Javascript functionality of the browser itself.

Comment: @pbaris maybe some example would be nice for the 50 rep. :)

Answer (score 3):

An example

AS3

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class MyApp extends Sprite {

        private var btn:Sprite;

        public function MyApp() {
            //add an entry point from js (html page) to swf, so js can call the swfFunc
            ExternalInterface.addCallback('swfFunc', swfFunc);

            btn = new Sprite();
            btn.mouseEnabled = true;
            btn.x = 0;
            btn.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 0);
            btn.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 300, 50);
            btn.graphics.endFill();
            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, jsFunc);
            addChild(btn);
        }

        public function jsFunc(evt:MouseEvent):void {
            // call the js function named jsFunc 
            ExternalInterface.call('jsFunc', 'Test JS');
        }

        //this method is called from the js
        public function swfFunc(text:String):void {
            trace(text);
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<object id='MySWF' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='MyApp.swf' width='300' height='50'>
    <param name='movie' value='MyApp.swf' />
    <param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always' />
    <param name='swliveconnect' value='true' />
</object>

<div id="container">
    A Text
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="swfFunc();">Call SWF</button>
```

JS

```
function jsFunc(text) {
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = text;
}

function swfFunc() {
    var swfObj =  window['MySWF'] || documment['MySWF'];
    swfObj.swfFunc('Test SWF');
}
```

Comment: I already know about ExternalInterface, I'm asking for how red.swf in question is able to do it without JS. Also the example seems like copied from a website .. ?

Answer (score 3):

Got it!
No Javascript, just as you said.
Sneaky piece of code, I don't fully understand why, but managed to get it working.
Downloaded and decompiled red.swf, and has 2 frames, only the second one has code which is the following (comments are mine)

```
    /*

flashvars are loaded to the _root as following:
_root.web = www.agitehabbero.com/index.php&creador=supercito
oddly the amperesand (&) gets interpreted too so we also get.
_root.creador=supercito

*/
    stop();
    var url = _root.web;
    if ("supercito" == _root.creador) {//verifies that the url passed has a value pair creador=supercito I guess to avoid it being used for something else?
        getURL ("http://supercito.com.ar/g3/web.php?url=" + url, "glu");
        /* the getURL calls this site, in a new window (frames are treated as windows by browsers) 
        somehow flash , as it doesn't find the frame or window, converts it into a pop up */
    } else {
        getURL ("http://supercito.com.ar/404", "glu");
    }
```

Oh, and this is barely ActionScript 2, looks like AS1 (which uses the same VM).

To test further I simplified the flash code and uploaded to a server:

```
stop();
getURL ("http://supercito.com.ar/g3/web.php?url=" + _root.web, _root.marco);
```

In the server now we can play with different inputs and see what happens.
The link is:
http://m0.cl/t/dwit/assets/no-usar/testing-odd.php

(sorry for the messy address I was in the middle of something else)
If we use any value for the frame param the http: / / supercito.com.ar page loads and makes the window into a pop-up unless we use _self.
The thing is I can't see the part where this new window turns into a pop up, maybe It's hidden in the jquery file it loads. Beats me. Even checked with Charles.
If anyone has an idea, let me know and I'll try.
Hope this helps.
This is my first post here :)

**EDIT:**
I uploaded a modification for better testing.
Now we can change the main URL also.

```
stop();
getURL (_root.main + _root.web, _root.marco);
```

**EDIT Nº2**
It's flash!
with the new setup, you can try any URL and it will make it into a pop-up as long as the targeted window is not _self or _top, the thing is, that Chrome interprets it as a pop-up, but IE just reads it as a _blank window.
Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I remember back in the day we also used `getURL()` to inject javascript, but this is not the case.

Comment: How does the PHP file on supercito do it? You say "the actual workings are well known" and "I can't see the part where this new window turns into a pop up"

Comment: I was wrong about that, I thought it was changing the window properties, but it turns out it was flash. (must edit the answer)

Comment: I'm having trouble recreating this - what does web.php do?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to open a new browser window from Flash (with no help from the HTML page): http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/create-pop-browser-windows-flash.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's possible.

Modern browsers have rather strong pop-up blockers which, in most cases, do not allow opening a new window/tab if there is no user interaction.

Even if you manage to trick one browser there is a possibility that it won't work in different browser/OS.

BTW, if there is no JS on the page and you can't edit HTML you can run JS directly from Flash using a 'pseudo-protocol':

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('javascript:void(alert('This is called from Flash'))');
navigateToURL(req);
```

So, in theory, you could have quite complex JS 'injected' onto your HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

First you should make sure you're using window.top.document.  From there try opening the window -- if your window handle is null, then open a 100% iframe.

```
    /**
     *  @public
     */
    public function JSTest():void {

        ExternalInterface.call('eval', [

            "window.createFrame = function() {",
                "var doc                = window.top.document;",
                "var ifrm               = doc.createElement('IFRAME');",
                "ifrm.style.position    = 'absolute';",
                "ifrm.style.left        = '0';",
                "ifrm.style.top         = '0';",
                "ifrm.style.width       = '100%';",
                "ifrm.style.height      = '100%';",
                "ifrm.setAttribute('src', 'http://vimeo.com');",
                "doc.body.appendChild(ifrm);",
            "}",

            // try opening window, otherwise, open an iframe
            "if (!window.open('http://www.vimeo.com', '_top')) {",
                "window.createFrame();",
            "}"

        ].join('\n'));

    }
```